# How to seed database with JSON in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I have a json file with these values:
[image: My JSON]

and I have to make a MSSQL database for it using ASP.NET MVC and Entity framework. My question would be of two parts.

1. How do I seed the database with this JSON?
2. How should my model look or be written? I'm particularly curious about the specs and image part.

[Edit]
Seed Method

```
        using (StreamReader jsonData = new StreamReader(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Resources/products.json")))
        {
            List<Product> products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(jsonData.ReadToEnd());
            products.ForEach(s => context.Products.AddOrUpdate(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

[Edit]
My model:

```
    public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public double price { get; set; }

    public string specsmanufacturer { get; set; }

    public int specsstorage { get; set; }

    public string specsos { get; set; }

    public int specscamera { get; set; }

    public string imagesmall { get; set; }

    public string imagelarge { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: For 1, you can use Json.Net to deserailize your json into entities. For you canjust store the path like that or refine the path before storing it into your database.

Comment: you mean how to insert it into the database? It depends on the table structure. Have you designed one? Or do you just want to place the JSON into a single field? It's not really clear what you mean, or what your issue is. What have you tried so far? As for a model structure (your second point), specs and image would be objects which are properties of the main object, just like they are in the Json. Probably they'd each be of a different type to the main object. Or you could just serialise to a flattened object, if that has no value.

Comment: @ADyson if you would've read the question a few times you would clearly see I haven't designed one, I'm just asking for the best way to do this and how to post it into database :)

Comment: Sorry I only read it once, apologies for not reading it multiple times, I didn't know that was required. :-) Anyway...we don't know the business requirements which might inform the structure, we don't know if any of these values are fixed items to be chosen from a list of pre-defined values- we don't know a lot of detail, in fact. But just based on that one small snippet of data, you could in theory place all of those values into separate columns in one single table. Maybe that suits your overall requirements, maybe not. Difficult to know.

Comment: This is an assignment I have to do and literally I have given all the information I know, so that's it, If I knew more, I wouldn't have asked a question, youre missing the point.

Comment: So this is homework? Have you tried anything yet? The best way to learn is by doing. We can spoon feed you an answer which might or might not be what your course tutor had in mind, but no-one gains much from that. I've given you some hints though. You can find more about the specifics of doing this kind of task via EF Code First online through tutorials and documentation (and previous answers on here) already. Do you also have to deserialise this JSON from somewhere as part of this? Again that process is quite easy to research on google.

Comment: Basically the "right" answer to this is whatever is simplest, works correctly and best suits all the available requirements. If you've given us all the possible info, then unless this bit of the course is supposed to be about studying some particular topic around data structures which you're supposed to be taking into account and using some arbitrary technique or design pattern, then probably a flat table structure will be sufficient, or three tables as suggested in the answer would work too. It's really up to you, do what works.

Comment: I'm sorry to say again but youre missing the point. No, this is not homework. this is not for university/school/anything. but this is an assignment. That's not the point. the point is the question. and the question asks not "DO THE TASK FOR ME" but "what is the best way to do the task".

Comment: "This is an assignment"...what's an assignment if it's not homework? Anyway as I've just mentioned, "best" is entirely subjective in this situation, if there are no further requirements to take into account. Do the simplest thing which works.

Comment: maybe it's using Json.net maybe its creating 3 models, maybe its creating one model and in the specs field doing some kind of magic (I dont know what). That's what Im asking.

Comment: Oh my god, please, If you dont have an answer, just leave, I am not going to talk about what is this for, its not part of the question.

Comment: I don't have an answer because there is no "best" way to do it, there are only ways which succeed in meeting the requirements, and ways which don't, especially since the requirements are utterly trivial

Comment: There is a best way to do it, there's always is, you and I just probably dont know it. Thats why I asked.

Comment: Well what exactly would your definition of "best" be, then? What criteria do you attach to that, other than "it works"? Performance? Minimal amount of code? Shortest development cycle? Most testable? Somehow re-usable? Maintainability? Using some specific design or architectural principles? Uses least amount of external libraries? People's definition of good code, beyond "meets the basic requirements" varies enormously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either flatten your model (1 class 1 table) or store the entities in their respective tables (3 classes 3 tables).

**Edit: flat class model.**

```
public class Thingy
{
   [Key]
   public int ID{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public decimal Price{get;set;}
   public string SpecsManufacturer{get;set;}
   public int SpecsStorage{get;set;}
   public string SpecsOS{get;set;}
   //etc
}
```

If you are using Code-first and have a `Configuration.cs` in your Migrations folder then you can override the Seed method:

```
protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
{
   //Populate using whatever method you want.
}
```

The Seed method runs every time you run the command `update-database` against your database.

Comment: if I were to do it as 1 table, how would the specs part look? a list or something like that?

Comment: I edited my answer. You would have to handle the mapping from JSON to object manually as I doubt it's smart enough to flatten the structure for you.

Comment: I'm seeding the data like in my example (see edit), but I get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Which of your objects is null?

Comment: It was because of the Web.Server. I changed it to a regular directory and now it works better, my problem now is that it adds the name id and price values but others arent added. maybe know why @Wurd

Comment: You can't deserialize an object into a class that doesn't match it without doing manual mapping. Get your deserialized class http://json2csharp.com/ then map it to your database class manually or using automapper or something like that.